# Split function in twig drupal

Tags: split, twig, drupal-8

In a template, I have a statement like this:

```
{% set titles = content.field_titles|split('_') %}
```

But when I use this, nothing happens.

```
<h4>{{ titles[0] }}</h4>
```

However if I use this statement, I have a result.

```
{{ content.field_titles }}
// return : Description_Technical sheet_Support_Vinyl function_Product application_Versions
```

I do not know why it does not work.

Comment: `|split` was implemented in Twig 1.10.3, and works as expected. http://twigfiddle.com/4romqh - can you create a fiddle that reproduces the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

content.field_titles is probably not directly a string but an object representing a list of values (like FieldItemList)

you should try something more like this:

```
{% for rawTitle in content.field_titles %}
  {% set title = rawTitle.value|split('_') %}
  <h4>{{ title[0] }}</h4>
{% endfor %}
```